Argument type is not assignable to parameter type problem in IdentityDbContext
I am currently using .Net Framework Identity
And been following a video tutorial.
namespace SwmmDashboard
{
    public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options) { 
        
        }

        public DbSet<Device> Devices { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Parameter> Parameters {  get; set; }
        public DbSet<DataCollection> DataCollections { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    }
}

I have this code where I added IdentityDbContext
which is located in a different project but in the same solution. it migrated smoothly and the database updated.
but now in a different project for UI called SwmmUI,
     public Task<IActionResult> OnPostExportAsync()
 {
     return _impAndExp.Export(_context);
 }

The _context is in red stating that
Screenshot of the error
I tried reinstalling the nuget but the error is still there

What I did was just to delete the duplicated AppDbContext from the other project and consolidated it to one context in the backend project of the solution, so basically, mixing both contexts
